# Sorting each mysql results using Ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

On **page1.php** I call **page2.php** (Lijst of cars or boats) using Ajax. Afterwards I want to sort the results using another Ajax query.

The 2 jqueries codes on **page1.php**:

```
function display_cars() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'page2.php?action=cars',
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#show_results').html(msg);
        }
    });
}


function display_boats() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'page2.php?action=boats',
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#show_results').html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

On **page2.php** I have the mysql queries:

```
if ($action == "car") {
    $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE cars = $cars
    ORDER BY date DESC
    ";
}

if ($action == "boats") {
    $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE boats = $boats
    ORDER BY date DESC
    ";
}
```

The results of this mysql query:

> Mercedes: 50
>
> BMW: 10
>
> HONDA: 20

Now I want to sort ***each*** results by (ORDER BY quantity DESC) using Ajax.

I was thinking about using php sessions, but I am not sure if it the right solution.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks. I just did. Do you mean that my question is not clear enough and that I have to add more information and explanations?

Comment: I think the "meta-question's" accepted answer is self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

You can call ajax like this

```
function sort_boats() {
    var data = {
       action:"boats",
       sort:"desc"
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'page2.php',
    data:data,
    success: function(msg) {
    $('#show_results').html(msg);
    }
    });
    }
```

in php try this

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])&&isset($_GET['sort'])) {
   $action = $_GET['action'];
   $sort = $_GET['sort'];
   $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE boats = $action 
    ORDER BY date DESC , quantity $sort";
}
```

You can simply do this by using ORDER BY on quantity in your sql query  assuming it is one of the column of your table.

PS: use POST for better security.

Comment: changed my answer as per your question hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Vikram. This is not the solution I need. What about if I have +100 categories (Cars, boats, ...)? It will be almost impossible to use a seperate Ajax code for each item.

Comment: **SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE categories=$category ORDER BY date DESC** you can do this as well . You should also mention _table_ your working with for better answers.

Comment: My question is just an example.

Comment: for your example least provide how your table looks like in structure on which your trying to fire your query... for example name | quantity | date